# red/rebol: Subtracting dates returns days, how can I change that?

Tags: date, types, rebol, red

Playing with the date type, I was wondering, why a subtraction always returns days, how can I make it return minutes (or seconds, etc.), which could be possible in the second example

```
>> 24-dec-2016 - now
== 82
>> 24-dec-2016/0:00 - now
== 82
```

is that just arbitrary or can I influence what is returned? I tried around a bit with refinements, but would appreciate a push in a direction, the rebol/red way.

Maybe there is a more substantial thing below that question: what's the "rule" of what a subtraction returns, common sense, some kinda discussion and agreement or is it just determined by who implements it? (e.g. the result of subtracting: `1.1.1.1 - 1`, `200x200 - 100`, ...)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `difference`:

```
difference 24-dec-2016 now
== 1952:06:01
```

To get specific parts, use path syntax:

```
time-diff: difference 24-dec-2016 now
time-diff/2
```

Gives the minutes (the second component)

```
== 1951:42:11
== 42
```

Comment: Further, you can do **to integer! time-diff** to get the number of seconds.

Answer (score 2):

✓ Check out [Francois Vanzeveren's Date-Time Script on REBOL.org](http://www.rebol.org/download-a-script.r?script-name=date-time.r)

If you load it, i.e.,

```
do http://www.rebol.org/download-a-script.r?script-name=date-time.r
```

then you can do this:

```
>> ? date-dif
USAGE:
  DATE-DIF date1 date2 /y /m /d /ym /md /yd

DESCRIPTION:

  Returns the difference between two dates.

   DATE-DIF is a function value.

ARGUMENTS:
   date1 -- (Type: date)
   date2 -- (Type: date)
REFINEMENTS:
   /y -- Returns the number of complete years between @date1
and @date2.
   /m -- Returns the number of complete months between @date
1 and @date2.
   /d -- Returns the number of complete days between @date1
and @date2.
   /ym -- Returns the number of full months between @date1 a
nd @date2,
      not including the difference in years.
   /md -- Returns the number of full days between @date1 and
@date2,
      not including the difference in months.
   /yd -- Returns the number of full days between @date1 and
@date2,
      not including the difference in years.
```

✓  `>> ? now` to see the /refinements for dates

```
>> ? now
USAGE:
    NOW /year /month /day /time /zone /date /weekday /yearday
/precise

DESCRIPTION:
     Returns the current local date and time.
     NOW is a native value.

REFINEMENTS:
     /year -- Returns the year only.
     /month -- Returns the month only.
     /day -- Returns the day of the month only.
     /time -- Returns the time only.
     /zone -- Returns the time zone offset from GMT only.
     /date -- Returns date only.
     /weekday -- Returns day of the week as integer (Monday is
 day 1).
     /yearday -- Returns day of the year (Julian)
     /precise -- Use nanosecond precision
```

Example:

```
>> d: 27-7-1973
== 27-Jul-1973
>> d/day
== 27
>> d/month
== 7
>> d/year
== 1973
```